# In x86 architecture, does "push offset [name of variable]" push the address of that variable onto the activation record?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

If not, what does get pushed and where does it go?

I'm trying to write an MASM program that involves passing variables by reference.

Comment: The term "activation record" is somewhat unfamiliar, but if you mean the stack, then yes, it pushes the address of that variable (or to be exact, its offset in the segment it resides in - in a flat memory model, that is "the address") on the stack. In a segmented memory model like the 8086 used, it really means the offset. The address is then formed by the combination of segment and offset.

Answer (score 0):

The term "activation record" is somewhat unfamiliar, but if you mean the stack, then yes, it pushes the address of that variable (or to be exact, its *offset* **in** the *segment* it resides in - in a **flat** memory model, like in 32 bit or 64 bit Intel-compatible platforms, that is "the address") on the stack.

In a **segmented** memory model like the 16 bit 8086 used, it really means the *offset* and nothing else. The (so called "far") address is then formed by the combination of *segment* and *offset*.

Comment: The activation record is the stack of the function, in this case the one that is about to be called ("activated"), FYI.

Comment: Thanks, @Stefano. I realized that this term has become more popular lately, and means more than just the stack (and it does not even have to be on a stack at all). But the use of "push" already told me a stack was meant. <g>